# Convergent and divergent series.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

1) Suppose $\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$ both converges.

a) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

b) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n*b_n)$ converge always, sometimes  or never?

c) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty max(a_n,b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

d) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty min(a_n,b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

2) Suppose $\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n$  converges and $\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$ diverges.

a) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

b) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n*b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

c) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty max(a_n,b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

d) Does $\sum _{n=0}^\infty min(a_n,b_n)$ converge always, sometimes or never?

This is my answer:

For 1) because  $\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$ both converges, $a_n and b_n$ converges to zero, so $a_n+b_n$ converges to zero

a) Since $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n +\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$, so yes it always converges.

b) Since $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (\alpha a_n)= \alpha \sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n $ and since $b_n ->0$ we can treat it as a constant $\alpha$, so yes it always converges.

For c), and d) I'm not sure  how to reasoning these.

For 2) because $\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n$  converges and $\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$ diverges , so $a_n ->0$ but $b_n$ may not converge to zero.

a) Since $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n +\sum _{n=0}^\infty b_n$, so yes it sometime converges.

b) Since $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (\alpha a_n)= \alpha \sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n $ and since $b_n$ may or may not converge to zero, so we can't treat it as a constant $\alpha$ all the time, so yes it sometime converges.

For c), and d) I'm not sure  how to reasoning these.

Is my reasoning correct? I'm working on making convincing argument, so please feel free to point out my mistake.

Comment: TL:DR. Your answer to the first one is unconvincing. A justification can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418150/elementary-proof-convergence-of-a-linear-combination-of-convergent-series).

Comment: More than unconvincing I'd say the answer to (1)(a) is wrong, as it  points directly to $\;a_n\to 0\implies \sum a_n\;$ converges, which is completely false.

Comment: (b) Is "sometimes", so your answer is wrong.

Comment: (c) and (d) for the 1st question are correct because both $\max$ and $\min \{ a_n, b_n \}$ are either $a_n$ or $b_n$, which are known to converge

Comment: @DonAntonio oh, so for 1a) $a_n+b_n$ converges to zero, so the series may or may not converge, so the answer is sometime, the same as 1b)?

Comment: 1(a) is *always*, @DianeVanderwaif . It comes from the fact that the sum of converging sequences is converging. For (b) you're given a nice counterexample below, but sometimes the product does converge (for example, when the convergence is absolute)

Comment: thanks guys, what about my answer in part 2? are they correct?

Comment: For two: (a) Never, (b) Sometimes, (c) Sometimes (d) sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many questions can be answerd using the definition: the series

$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_n$$
is convergent if the partial sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$$
is convergent.

For 1.b) the answer is sometimes: take for example
$$a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n+1}}$$

Comment: The answer for 1(b) is "sometimes". There is no "no" option there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean that if $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ are convergent then $\sum_n a_nb_n$ isn't (*always*) convergent.

Comment: I don't think that's what's to be understood there, @sami

Comment: your example for 1b is undefined since you can't divide zero.